# Quoted initializer for unsigned char array in C

Tags: c, char, unsigned, initializing

This seems to work in GCC and Visual C without comment:

```
static const **unsigned** char foo[] = "bar";
```

This is a salt being used in a unit test.  There are other ways to do it, but this is simplest and involves the least casting down the line.

Will this cause trouble with other compilers?

Comment: What are you worried about, why would it cause any trouble?

Comment: @Claris: Because a string literal represents an array of (plain) `char`. Normally you wouldn't be able to use an array of `char` to initialize an array of `unsigned char` -- but there's an explicit rule allowing it.

Answer (score 4):

This is safe, at least if you're using a conforming C compiler.

[N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.9 paragraph 14 says:

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string
>   literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces.
>   Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null
>   character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size)
>   initialize the elements of the array.

The C90 standard has essentially the same wording, so you don't need to worry about older compilers.

The *character types* are `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char`.

Interestingly, there's no corresponding guarantee for pointer initialization, so this:

```
const char *ptr = "hello";
```

is safe, but this:

```
const unsigned char *uptr = "hello";
```

is not -- and there doesn't seem to be a simple workaround.

Comment: Tongue in cheek: The pointers should be `const` because the strings they point at are constants.  But fixing that trivial omission doesn't fix the problem you're driving at.

Comment: `(const unsigned char *)"hello"` would be a simple workaround

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Probably. It does rely on some assumptions about the representations of `char` and `unsigned char`, but I think those assumptions are justified by the guarantees in the standard. (Feels a bit icky, though.)